# Linux SCP File transfer No space left on device?

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, scp

I am trying to transfer one zip file from a linux based machine to a Windows based using SCP.

I can go through the transfer ok but when it completes it says "No space left on device".

The destination of the share has a LOT of free space.  I am transferring a file of around 5 gig but theres several hundred gig free on the share.

I was thinking it might be an issue thh directory paths.  On the windows server box the share would be c:\folder  when I use SCP in linux I use /folder.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: The details on the SSH / SCP server implementation on the Windows side is missing. (Windows 10 / 2016 added a server, but this post long predates that)

Answer (score 2):

Just another guess: Is the SCP server running on the Windows machine a 64-bit software? If that's a 32-bit executable it will probably not support files over 4 GB (okay, GiB, so 4 x 1024 x 1024 x 1024 bytes).

Quick check: if you see "*32" in the Task Manager after the filename then that's a 32-bit executable. (See more: https://superuser.com/questions/358434/how-to-check-if-a-binary-is-32-or-64-bit-on-windows )

But if it's a 64-bit executable that still does not guarantee it can handle files over 4 GB...

Have you tried to transfer files about 4 GB? If a file below 4 GB (for example 3800 MB) is transferred without any problems but larger than 4 GB fails then the best guess is that SCP server can't handle this big files.

Another guess: there might be low disk space in the temp directory (opening %TEMP% will lead you there).

Comment: It depends on the application. Some 32 bit applications can deal with large files and some 64-bit applications can't. The easiest way to know is to read the client (and server's) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I was investiagted the same: it could be if you was trying to upload big files and just not done it (i.e in the Midnight Commander (mc)) it will saved in the /tmp and it could be over 1Gb, thats why it could notify "No space left on device"..
Try to check the free space on the LOCAL machine and check the "/tmp":

```
 # df -Th
 ...
 tmpfs          tmpfs    1001M 1001M     0 100% /tmp
 ...
```

In this case you need to remove files (seems from previous transfers) like this:

```
 # rm /tmp/mc-root/*
```

Comment: Not exactly the answer to the question, but certainly the answer to my problem!

Answer (score 0):

I always use Winscp to use scp on windows and never had a problem.

In addition could you provide the command and program you are running?

Comment: CentOS scp -v /backup/site/file.gz admin@IPADDRESS:/folder  I beleive it is winscp on the windows box

Comment: And what daemon is running on windows to accept this?

Comment: Also, why not just go on the windows machine and pull it with winscp?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Windows doesn't have a native SCP implementation. That's a rather key piece of information, to be honest. If you aren't running an SSH service with SCP, you're stuck until you sort that out.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but: Check if the server to which you want to copy the file have enough space on C drive for this file. It is possible that the receiver is placing the file in the temp directory where it is attaching the rest of the file parts during the transfer...

Also check if correct permission has been set, both to the share and NTFS. If the deamon have rights to write.

Check if there is a per user quota implemented on the drive/share.

Comment: Yes, that drive has over 100gig free.  The file I am transferring is around 5gig

Comment: did you checked if correct NTFS permission has been set? Is the deamon which is handling the transfer has the write/modify/delete permissions? Is this a windows server? If yes - is there a quota implemented per user?